# Add qml module with plugin in qt resource

Tags: qml, qt5, qtplugin, qt-resource

We have a qmldir declare a module contains qml files which are put inside resource file. The module has plugin which is in a directory, but not resource.

Before add qmldir and qml files into resource, everything works fine.

But now, when running app I get component is not ready, module is not installed error.

The dir contains qml files is like this:

```
ComponentA
ComponentB
private
    privateComponents
    plugin.dll
    plugin.lib
    qmldir
resources.qrc
qmldir
```

I think the problem is the module defined in qmldir inside private folder:
[private/qmldir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuFIs.png)

I do add importPath import the path defined in resource file.

But how can I declare plugin now? Since qml files are directly loaded into app, but plugins are not.